# impossible shape for affine variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

It's the content of Gathmann's AG.

> In $X=\mathbb{A}^2$ , the union of the open subprevariety $U=\mathbb{A}\times (\mathbb{A\setminus\left\{0\right\}})$ and the closed subprevariety $Y=\left\{0\right\}$ , as in the picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEylq.png) 
> does not have a natural structure as a subprevariety of $\mathbb{A}^2$(since it does not look like an affine variety in a neighborhood of the origin).

I don't know why it does not look like an affine variety in a neighborhood of the origin.
Does that has something with the dimension or connectivity?
Any help will be grateful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, from your post I don't really understand what your question or problem is; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: Thank you for your advice ! I'm pretty sorry .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is, if you take an open neighborhood of the origin in $U\cup Y$, by definition of the subspace topology, it is the intersection of an open set $V \subset X$ with $U\cup Y$, but those intersections can never be affine. The reason for this is that if they were affine the not only had to include the origin, but also the rest of the x-axis they would intersect in $X$. This relates closely to the example *4.18* why $\mathbb A^2\backslash\{0\}$ is not affine.

In this case take any open set $V$ in $U\cup Y$ containing the origin. If it were affine we could find a distinguished open set $D(f)$ that contained the origin, because they form a basis of our topology. But now the coordinate ring of $D(f)\cap(U\cup Y)$ is the same as just of $D(f)$.
Then $D(f)\cap(U\cup Y)$ would need to include other points from the x-axis, as polynomials in one indeterminate only have finitely many zeros, this is a contradiction.